# Splitting one emission into several

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have one observable, `numberRange$`, that emits an array of numbers, say `[65, 66, 67, 68]`.

Is there any number to subscribe to `numberRange$` and getting each number in the array as a separate emission in the new pipe?

Each number will be used as an input to an async http-call, and with `mergeMap` it is trivial to batch the http-calls as the api only allows 2 parallell computations at once.

For now, I am subscribing to `numberRange$` and saving the output in a variable `numberRange$` and using `rxjs/operators.from(numberRange).pipe(mergeMap(someFunc, batchCount))` to perform the operation, but I would rather directly pipe `numberRange$` and split the array into separate emissions before hitting `mergeMap`.

Thanks for good answers!

Comment: You can use just `mergeAll()`, eg.: `numberRange$.pipe(mergeAll()).subscribe()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, I think you could use `mergeMap` to split the emitions.

```
numberRange$.pipe(
    mergeMap(nums => nums) // mergeMap(nums => from(nums))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concatMap`:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

of([65, 66, 67, 68]).pipe(concatMap(x => x)).subscribe(console.log);
```